# Changing UIAlertView Button text size or Button Width size

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertview, font-size

I am showing alert to the user to pick an option. First option has less text than the second one, so in UIAlertView, First button text size to large and second ones is small.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this ? I just want both the texts of same size. I tried giving newline character, but it doesn't work. Or any way to change buttons width/height so that text can fit there in same font size.

Thanks.